# Initiating a DTLS connection

Tags: networking, telephony, webrtc

I am running a Janus WebRTC gateway on a Windows 10 Professional computer. Using this gateway I am calling a soft phone (Xlite) in our LAN from a Firefox browser (on Microsoft Azure virtual machine).

The issue I am facing is that after ICE completes successfully the DTLS connection is not initiated by Janus (verified with Wireshark). If I use another network interface (Logmein Hamachi) then the DTLS connection is initiated by Janus successfully and the media flows as expected.

I have configured Janus to use UDP ports (incoming) in the range 50000 to 50050. The required UDP ports are open the firewall. The outgoing UDP ports (49152 to 65535) are open on the firewall (Clear OS). I confirmed that the incoming and outgoing ports are open using the Socket Test Tool and
also used Open SSL to successfully initiate a DTLS connection between the computers

I logged all the traffic using Wireshark but did not notice the application using ports that it was not expected to use.

Thanks in advance for any tips to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. This problem was occurring because I had enabled the Nat 1_1 mapping feature without the computer on which Janus was hosted being assigned a public IP address. Once I removed that option things became OK.

Thanks and regards
Mathew